# Fade with element Transition

Tags: vue.js

I have a list and I am running it with vue. But I'd like to use the fade effect to change its value. But it is not working with the tag

Here is an example where I have the transition effect working with v-if, but it does not work with the list transition

```
new Vue({
el:'#test',
data:{
    counter:0,
    show:true,
    foo:['a','b','c']
}

})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kv3s2y6z/2/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> When toggling between elements that have the same tag name, you must tell Vue that they are distinct elements by giving them unique **key** attributes. Otherwise, Vue’s compiler will only replace the content of the element for efficiency. Even when technically unnecessary though, it’s considered good practice to always key multiple items within a  component.

Also the transition must be on **out-in mode**.

HTML:

```
<div id="test">
  <transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
    <p :key="foo[counter]">
      {{ foo[counter] }}
    </p>
  </transition>
  <button @click="counter++">
    next
  </button>
  <button  @click="counter--">
    before
  </button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
new Vue({
 el:'#test',
 data:{
  counter:0,
  show:true,
  foo:['a','b','c']
 }
})
```

Snippet:
https://jsfiddle.net/L4r64yxk/

Comment: WOW! This should be clarified more often! I was stuck with this for hours